# Adjustment for Bathroom Faucet Handles?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I just installed a new bathroom faucet and I'm having difficulty in regard to having good control of the water flow/pressure with the handles:

The faucet has a hot and a cold handle.  The handles turn 90 degrees from closed to full open.  The problem is that adjusting the water flow only seems to take place on about 30 degrees of the turn, with the remaining 60 degrees letting the water out at full blast.  This makes it extremely difficult to adjust the water without temperature across the two handles....it's usually too hot or too cold since it requires such fine tuning to get it just warm.

At first, I thought I could just limit the water by closing the shutoff valves under the sink a little, but everyone seems to advise against that, seems like those should always be fully open.  And nobody seems to complain about this issue on the reviews of the faucet.

Is there any way to correct this?

[Click here for link to the faucet in question](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Edgewood-8-in-Widespread-2-Handle-High-Arc-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Brushed-Nickel-67392W-6104/206428544)

Comment: Do both sides function as you describe if operated alone? That doesn't seem right, and there's no adjustment for it. You may need to exchange the faucet for another of the same or a different type.

Comment: Are your faucet handles asymmetric levers which are affected by gravity so they open farther from your setpoint spontaneously? Or is it water pressure which is causing them to open farther than where you have set them? The cold faucet on my lavatory is very easy to turn (very little resistance) and has an asymmetric lever handle so that both water pressure and gravity caused it to open further than where I set it. I re-positioned the handle so that at the setting I use for shaving the lever is down and there is no gravitational force pulling it further.

Comment: I have a Price Pfister two handle lavatory faucet. Maybe there is a friction adjustment which I haven't tried to adjust. We have an undersized tankless central gas-fired  water heater and the pressure under flow of the hot is less than the cold. I have no problem with the hot side faucet moving from the set point.

Comment: @isherwood Both faucets work as described if operated alone.

Comment: @JimStewart  I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to answer your question.  Not sure what "set point" and "asymmetric lever" means.  The best I can offer is the spec docs for this specific faucet.
http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/27/2751fd43-2658-4a28-8095-4f840a8dfc6b.pdf
http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/b4/b4391d45-6d7e-4f10-af8b-5f1ca9590861.pdf

Comment: In general, our water pressure is very good throughout the house, even the shower in the basement blasts pretty good.  Maybe I will have to call the manufacturer on this?  However, I'm wondering if it is in fact operating properly, as I have the same exact issue on both handles.

Comment: Mine is like this but at an angle down toward the sink so that gravity pulls down on the lever handle if it is in any position but directly toward the lavatory. https://assets.nationalbuildersupply.com/images/productimages/pfister-g148-6000.jpg;width=230;height=230;bgcolor=White

Comment: I repositioned the lever handles so that at the normal operating position (i.e., 'set point') they point straight toward the lavatory or a little past and so gravity does not exert a force to open further. The lever handles are heavy. I can still turn on the water full when I want though it does clank against the spigot. I think Pfister must have discontinued this angled lavatory faucet just for the reason that I found it necessary to reposition the lever.

Comment: I am just wondering if this faucet has an anti scauld feature this could limit the temp range.

Comment: There's no limit on the temp range.  I think it may just be a crappy faucet.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: This was never resolved.  However, I did happen to find the exact faucet in a restaurant restroom and it had the same issue.  I think it's just a bad design.  I think it cost $100, so it's a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you describe seems to me to be normal for these faucets with individual handles for hot and cold and long life cartridges or ceramic disk seals, as opposed to the old type with a rubber washer sealing on a brass seat.